# Is the resistance 0 in the ballistic regime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, projectile

Given that in the ballistic regime a particle (electron) can move freely without scattering (there are no impurities ), is the resistance through a ballistic sample zero?

Comment: This is an old and well-understood question in mesoscopic physics. The resistance of the wire itself is zero, but there is inevitable voltage drop in the resistive contacts which gives total conductance e^2/h per channel per spin component.

Comment: @Slaviks What if the contacts were superconducting?

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

> Ballistic conduction or Ballistic transport is the transport of electrons in a medium having *negligible* electrical resistivity caused by scattering. Without scattering, electrons simply obey Newton's second law of motion at non-relativistic speeds. Ballistic conduction is the *unimpeded* flow of charge, or energy-carrying particles, over relatively long distances in a material.

[Ballistic Conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction)

Comment: From the same Wikipedia page: "Therefore, even in the case of a perfect ballistic transport, there is a fundamental ballistic conductance which saturates the current of the device with a resistance of approximately $h/ (2 e^2 M)$ (spin degeneracy included)"

Comment: @Slaviks How can I physically understnd this resistance (i.e. what is the intuition behind it)?

Comment: In order to describe the contact with a potential, charge carriers injected into it from a ballistic conductor must thermalize - otherwise the concept of "voltage" is not applicable. This inevitable thermalization in the contact is the source of the "quantum resistance". Try to read Imry's book or http://rmp.aps.org/pdf/RMP/v71/i2/pS306_1

Comment: @Hasan I down-voted since this is the wrong answer. Slaviks gave the correct one, please correct your answer according to her/his remark. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Slaviks Your reference goes beyond a paywall. I guess you mean: M. van Rossum and T. Nieuwenhuizen, Rev. Mod. Phys. 71, 313 (1999). It is available on the arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9804141 Thanks for your correct answer also :-)